# How can i inflate Relative layout

Tags: android

I got a task to inflate the XML view. I really don't understand what to do. I 
 used a base adapter.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    //TODO - Get the current ToDoItem
    final ToDoItem toDoItem =  mItems.get(position);

    //TODO - Inflate the View for this ToDoItem
    // from todo_item.xml.

      RelativeLayout itemLayout =(RelativeLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout1);
     View InflatedView= null;
```

todo_item.xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView>
  <!-- some code -->
</TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I followed something like shown below

```
RelativeLayout itemLayout = 
 (RelativeLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout1);
    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.todo_item, parent, false);
    if(convertView==null){
        convertView= new RelativeLayout(mContext);
    }
```

but this didn't work. I also didn't understand the convertView which is passed to getview method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ListView` API has a few eccentricities.

The `convertView` parameter given to you in `getView()` is actually nullable. It's how `ListView` lets you recycle views as the user scrolls through the list. Because of this, you cannot use it to inflate your `RelativeLayout`.

To obtain your view, you should first check if `convertView` is null. If it is, then you need to inflate the `View` using the `parent` parameter that's given to you.

```
RelativeLayout itemLayout;

if (convertView != null) {
  itemLayout = (RelativeLayout) convertView;
} else {
  LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context);
  itemLayout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.todo_item, parent, false);
}
```